# What happen to categories on the same name?

Tags: objective-c

Say A is subclass of B

Say A has a category doThis.

B also has a category doThis.

Say I did

```
B* b = [[B alloc]init];
[b doThis];
```

Is there a guarantee that doThis declared in B+doThis.h will be the one called instead of A+doThis?

Sample:

in NSManagedObject+somecategories.m

```
+(void)vLoadBookmark
{
   //Just empty
}
```

Latter

in BusinessObject+somecategories.m where BusinessObject is a subclass of NSManagedObject

```
+(void)vLoadBookmark
{
   //Do something

}
```

If one day I called `[someBusinessObject vLoadBookmark]` will //Do something be reached?

Comment: B has method doThis therefore doThis will be called.

Comment: No. doThis is also a category of B

Comment: I think you have your subclass vs superclass terminology confused.  If `A` is a subclass of `B` and you instantiate `foo = [[B alloc] init]` it is absolutely impossible* for `[foo anything]` to call `A`'s implementation, since it's not a superclass. (*: barring some really, really inadvisable introspection)

Comment: Give us a very short, minimal implementation of what you intend, so it's clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a category overrides a method defined in another category, it is undefined what implementation will prevail.

From Apple's Programming with Objective-C > [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4):

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method
>   in the original class, or a method in another category on the same
>   class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which
>   method implementation is used at runtime.